# ¿Como unir cadenas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de unir el nombre, apellido paterno y apellido materno teniendo por ejemplo un resultado así: "Juan López Robles" vemos como al iniciar cada palabra es una letra mayúscula y la siguen las minúsculas seguido de un espacio y así sucesivamente con las demás palabras.
Lo que llevo es esto:

```
select id_empleado, 
       concat((concat(upper(left(nombre,1)),lower(substring(nombre,2))),' '), 
       concat(concat((upper(left(apellido_paterno,1)),lower(substring(apellido_paterno,2)))),' ')), 
       concat((upper(left(apellido_materno,1)),lower(substring(apellido_materno,2)))) 
       as nombre from empleado where id_empleado = 1
```

Pero no se como unir los concat intente usar concat() también pero me retornaba el error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Puede ser que te falte o este sobrado algún paréntesis

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante. Creo que la mejor forma de resolverla sería creando una función o procedimiento almacenado que tome en cuenta varias posibilidades: que cualquiera de los valores puede ser `NULL`; que cualquiera de los valores puede ser una cadena vacía `nadaaquí`, lo cual no es lo mismo que `NULL`; que cualquiera de los valores puede tener espacios en blanco sobrantes al principio o al final, por ejemplo `(espacio)pedro`, `pedro(espacio)`; que cualquiera de los valores puede estar escrito así: `pEdro`  o `pedrO`; que haya un solo apellido. Quizá haya más cosas a tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas **MYSQL** puedes usar `CONCAT_WS(" ",apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,nombre)`

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [`CONCAT_WS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat_ws.asp) que recibe como primer parametro un separador que une cada uno de los parametros recibidos:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("-", "es", "en", "fr"); // imprime: es-en-fr
```

En tu caso seria:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", nombre, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno) as nombreCompleto from empleado where id_empleado = 1
```